# Converting .docx to PDF, using Microsoft Word 2010, giving bad output

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-reader

I am making a brochure for my school fest. This is the screenshot while editing in Word:

[image]

But whenever I **Save it as** .pdf the following comes as the output:

[image]

It can be clearly seen from the images that the background in the editor is **not tiled** whereas in PDF equivalent it is. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install a PDF printer, such as PrimoPDF, and see if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: PrimoPDF is giving me the same output. This isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you described can be resolved by inserting this image in the header pane with wrapping set to "Behind text" as described in workaround: [Background image appears in tile view when I save to Pdf](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/background-image-appears-in-tile-view-when-i-save/e7e2c56a-4ea7-40b2-9c3c-f0f1c464f577?auth=1).

You should also insert section break on the first page so that your modification of the header only aplies to the first page.